# Is example1.example.com called multiple domain or subdomain?

Tags: domains, url, subdomain, multiple-domains

I have these sites, `example1.example.com`, `example2.example.com`, ... etc. I was wondering what is the proper term for that? I heard multi-domain, and subdomain being used. Are they interchangeable, if so, which term would better describe this?

Comment: subdomain is an addition part of your main domain and multiple domain means you can create more than one domain.example1 and example2 are subdomain of main your main domain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`example1` and `example2` are subdomains of `mysite.com`.

Multi-domain just means a site can be accessed by more than one domain name. Ie.e. two domains pull up the same website.

Answer (score 0):

`example1.mysite.com`, `example2.mysite.com` etc are the subdomains of your `mysite.com`